# AngularJS ng-options issue when linked to gapped Primary Key

Tags: mysql, angularjs, ng-options

I have an AngularJS ng-option set, and a SQL Server db with some "Champion" names.

I populate my ng-option using this list from the DB, but I am having some problems. Right now I use the following ng-option to setup my list.

```
<span>
   <select style="width:25%" ng-options="champ1.cID as champ1.cName for champ1 in Champions1 | orderBy: 'cName'" ng-init="0" ng-model="champ1" ng-change="part3Valid()">{{champ1.cName}}</select>
</span>
```

The issue here is that i "think" since my Primary Key list is broken/has gaps, it causes issues with displaying the correct image with the correct option name.

By Image, I mean that my options (on change) updates an image as follows.

```
Favorite Champions
<!--SET UP LE CHAMPS-->
<div>
   <span><img ng-src="/Content/champions/{{Champions1[champ1].cName.trim() || 'None'}}_Square_0.png" style="width:15%" /></span>
   <span><img ng-src="/Content/champions/{{Champions2[champ2].cName.trim() || 'None'}}_Square_0.png" style="width:15%" /></span>
   <span><img ng-src="/Content/champions/{{Champions3[champ3].cName.trim() || 'None'}}_Square_0.png" style="width:15%" /></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span><select style="width:25%" ng-options="champ1.cID as champ1.cName for champ1 in Champions1 | orderBy: 'cName'" ng-init="0" ng-model="champ1" ng-change="part3Valid()">{{champ1.cName}}</select></span>
  <span><select style="width:25%" ng-options="champ2.cID as champ2.cName for champ2 in Champions2 | orderBy: 'cName'" ng-init="0" ng-model="champ2" ng-change="part3Valid()">{{champ2.cName}}</select></span>
  <span><select style="width:25%" ng-options="champ3.cID as champ3.cName for champ3 in Champions3 | orderBy: 'cName'" ng-init="0" ng-model="champ3" ng-change="part3Valid()">{{champ3.cName}}</select></span>
</div>
```

So the actual list of names in my options is CORRECT and IN ORDER, but the images do not line up, for example the first option shown is for "Aaatrox", but it shows the image for "Akali". Hence why I think when I am updating the image (`Champions1[champ1].cName.trim()`), **I think am getting a differently ordered/structured list for the ng-src setup versus the ng-option setup**, but I am not sure how to fix this, or where the mis-align is coming from.

Here is my API call and the factory (stuck together for readability).

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GET()
{

    using (MoviesEntities db = new MoviesEntities())
    {
        var query = from champs in db.championLists
                    select new
                    {
                        cID = champs.ID,
                        cName = champs.Name,
                    };

        HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage();
        msg.Content = new ObjectContent<object>(query.OrderBy(x => x.cName).ToList(), new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

        msg.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return msg;
    }
}
  ---------------------------------------

app.factory('championService', function ($http) {
    var championService = {};
    championService.getResources = function () {
        return $http({
            url: '/API/APIChampions',
            method: "GET"
        })
    }
    return championService;
});
```

I set the service equal to champ1/2/3.

Here is my DB list, as you can see my PKID has some gaps so I think that may be an issue when I call it into my app? (*also note new names are added at end of list, even though I re-order it*)

> ```
> 1 None                                              
> 2 Aatrox                                            
> 3 Ahri                                              
> 4 Akali                                             
> 5 Alistar                                           
> 6 Amumu                                             
> 7 Anivia                                            
> 8 Annie                                             
> 9 Ashe                                              
> 10    Blitzcrank                                        
> 11    Brand                                             
> 12    Braum                                             
> 13    Caitlyn                                           
> 14    Cassiopeia                                        
> 15    Chogath                                           
> 16    Corki                                             
> 17    Darius                                            
> 18    Diana                                             
> 19    Draven                                            
> 20    DrMundo                                           
> 21    Elise                                             
> 22    Evelynn                                           
> 23    Ezreal                                            
> 25    Fiora                                             
> 26    Fizz                                              
> 27    Galio                                             
> 28    Gangplank                                         
> 29    Garen                                             
> 30    Gragas                                            
> 31    Graves                                            
> 32    Hecarim                                           
> 33    Heimerdinger                                      
> 34    Irelia                                            
> 35    Janna                                             
> 36    JarvanIV                                          
> 37    Jax                                               
> 38    Jayce                                             
> 39    Jinx                                              
> 40    Karthus                                           
> 41    Katarina                                          
> 42    Kayle                                             
> 43    Kennen                                            
> 45    Leblanc                                           
> 46    LeeSin                                            
> 47    Leona                                             
> 48    Lissandra                                         
> 49    Lucian                                            
> 50    Lulu                                              
> 51    Lux                                               
> 52    Malphite                                          
> 53    Malzahar                                          
> 54    Maokai                                            
> 55    MasterYi                                          
> 56    MissFortune                                       
> 57    Mordekaiser                                       
> 58    Morgana                                           
> 59    Nami                                              
> 60    Nasus                                             
> 61    Nautilus                                          
> 62    Nidalee                                           
> 63    Nocturne                                          
> 64    Nunu                                              
> 65    Olaf                                              
> 66    Orianna                                           
> 67    Pantheon                                          
> 68    Poppy                                             
> 69    Quinn                                             
> 70    Rammus                                            
> 71    Renekton                                          
> 72    Rengar                                            
> 73    Riven                                             
> 74    Rumble                                            
> 75    Ryze                                              
> 76    Sejuani                                           
> 77    Shaco                                             
> 78    Shen                                              
> 79    Shyvana                                           
> 80    Singed                                            
> 81    Sion                                              
> 82    Sivir                                             
> 83    Skarner                                           
> 84    Sona                                              
> 85    Soraka                                            
> 86    Swain                                             
> 87    Syndra                                            
> 88    Talon                                             
> 89    Taric                                             
> 90    Teemo                                             
> 91    Thresh                                            
> 92    Tristana                                          
> 93    Trundle                                           
> 94    Tryndamere                                        
> 95    TwistedFate                                       
> 96    Twitch                                            
> 97    Udyr                                              
> 98    Urgot                                             
> 99    Varus                                             
> 100   Vayne                                             
> 101   Veigar                                            
> 102   Vi                                                
> 103   Viktor                                            
> 104   Vladimir                                          
> 105   Volibear                                          
> 106   Warwick                                           
> 108   Xerath                                            
> 109   XinZhao                                           
> 110   Yasuo                                             
> 111   Yorick                                            
> 112   Zac                                               
> 113   Zed                                               
> 114   Ziggs                                             
> 115   Zilean                                            
> 116   Zyra                                              
> 117   Karma                                             
> 118   Khazix                                            
> 119   Velkoz                                            
> 120   Gnar                                              
> 123   Kalista                                           
> 124   RekSai                                            
> 126   KogMaw                                            
> 128   Wukong                                            
> 1122 FiddleSticks
> ```

Still newer to API calls and AngularJS so I am struggling with figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this: `Champions1[champ1].cName.trim()` you are accessing a position in the champions array which is not necessarily the same as the id you are passing.

But you can use ng-options like this:

```
ng-options="champ1.cName for champ1 in Champions1 | orderBy: 'cName'"
```

And then:

```
<img ng-src="/Content/champions/{{champ1.cName.trim() || 'None'}}_Square_0.png" style="width:15%" />
```

Or if you only need the name:

```
ng-options="champ1.cName as champ1.cName for champ1 in Champions1 | orderBy: 'cName'"
```

And then:

```
<img ng-src="/Content/champions/{{champ1.trim() || 'None'}}_Square_0.png" style="width:15%"/>
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU! Quick question, is there a way to initiate the ng-option to value "None" (which exists in my DB), rather than the blank option? Before I set it to 0, which is where None was for the PKID, but now that it's re-ordered None is in the middle of list for ng-option.

Comment: Yes, you can add `<option value="None">None</option>` inside your `select`.

Comment: Hmm that does not seem to fix it. Still a blank (empty) starting option

Comment: You need to initialise champ1 to 'None'. You can either do that on your controller or use `ng-init="champ1 = 'None'"` in your select.

Comment: Btw, for me it's Ryze, Tristana and Lux.

Comment: It seems that the default value needs to be empty. I tried to put it in a plnkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/WnPAGtmrj7oCVIX0ofmQ?p=preview

Comment: Well before we made the change I had it set to `None`, so I figured it would still be possible now :/